# Is it ok with entity-entity relationship in ER diagram?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

As the title says is it ok to have entity-entity relationships in ER diagrams?
I'm designing a database for a sports competition and would like to have that "teams" belong to certain "sports" and that "event" are certain "sports".

1. Teams((team_id), sport_id, country)
2. Sports((sport_id), sport, sub_category)
3. Event((event_id), sport_id, group)

Or is it better to represent them with relationships between ?

Comment: Where is the diagram?

Comment: I'm in the process of constructing the diagram and wonder if it is ok to connect two entities in the diagram without relationship in ER diagrams. All the ER diagrams in google docs i see has relationships between entities.

Comment: its better to represent relation between them so that others dont have to guess

Comment: Ok thanks! I figured out how to make it look neat! Thank you!